# How to convert miliseconds to timestamp with timezone in athena

Tags: timestamp, amazon-athena

I have a column in athena in miliseconds and I need to convert it to timestamp with timezone format.

I tried this code:

```
date_format(from_unixtime(cast(time_ms as bigint)/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

but it just gives the timestamp without timezone.

I want to be in format of '2019-10-30T08:13:03.215000'

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this way is a the best but this works:

```
date_format(from_unixtime(cast(time_ms as bigint)/1000, 'America/Los_Angeles'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```